# Check the prime numbers in the array and return the sum of the prime numbers

Tags: java, arrays, sum, primes

I tried to return the prime numbers in checkPrime. There must be some mistake in the checkPrime method itself and I cannot find it. What to do ?  the array is not returning any value

```
import java.util.*;
public class addPrimeInArray{
    int total=0; int i,j;

    int checkPrime(int[] arr){
        for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            boolean isPrime=true;
            for(j=2;j<arr[i];j++){
                if(arr[i]%j==0){
                    isPrime=false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(isPrime) {
                return(arr[i]);
            }
        }
        return(arr[i]);
    }
    int sum(int[] arr) {
        for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            total=total+arr[i];
        }
        return(total);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addPrimeInArray apa = new addPrimeInArray();
        int [] numbers = new int[3];
        numbers[0] = 1;
        numbers[1] = 2;
        numbers[2] = 3;
        for(int i: numbers) {
            System.out.print(i+" ");
        }
        apa.checkPrime(numbers);
        apa.sum(numbers);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know it ain't working?

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is `checkPrime`; it should take a single value and return true if that value is prime. The algorithm below is slightly optimized; we only need to test odd values (after checking two and its' multiples). Also, none of your methods depend on class state so I would remove the class fields and make the methods static.

```
static boolean checkPrime(int v) {
    if (v == 1 || v == 2) {
        return true;
    } else if (v % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    int sq = (int) Math.sqrt(v);
    for (int i = 3; i <= sq; i += 2) {
        if (v % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Next, the `sum` method should iterate the array and add it to the total if the number is prime (call `checkPrime` on that value). Like,

```
static int sum(int[] arr) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (checkPrime(arr[i])) {
            total += arr[i];
        }
    }
    return (total);
}
```

Finally, you can use `Arrays.toString(int[])` to print your array - and then sum the prime numbers in the array and display the result; like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3 };
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
    System.out.println("The sum of primes is " + sum(numbers));
}
```

Comment: why are you finding out the square root  and then increment i by +2 ?

Comment: Only terms less than or equal to the square root are possible factors, and we eliminated factors of 2 before the loop so need to retest them (+ 2 skips the evens).